# Serial console echoes back input

Tags: linux, console, serial, tty

Modified /etc/default/grub as below and successfully setup serial console on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200"
GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

On the serial console, I get an echo back of whatever input is provided.  If I type in

> ls /tmp

In the output below I get

> ls /tmp
>
> file1.txt file2.txt etc

The extra input in the output is more than just annoying. It messes with entering information on the input.

Is there a way to avoid the input from being echoed back?

Comment: What are you using as terminal emulator when talking to that console? Could be actually a problem on the terminal side in stead of the the grub-console.

Comment: I have tried "putty raw/telnet on Windows" and "telnet on Ubuntu".  All have the same behavior. putty has the option to "turn off local echo" which helped with not messing up the application, but then I cannot see what I am typing!